# Dynamically changing the title of a SiteMapNode

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, sitemap, sitemapprovider

We have a website that uses a bog-standard default sitemap with security trimming as follows:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="default" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" name="default" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

All very well, but a request has come in to change the `Title` of one node based on some back-end criteria. Sounds like a simple thing, but apparently not.

**Attempt 1** - Handling the `SiteMapResolve` event. It doesn't appear to matter *where* this event is handled, I have shown it in `Global.asax` merely because that was one of the places I tried it and it worked.

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        AddHandler SiteMap.SiteMapResolve, AddressOf SiteMapResolve
    End Sub

    Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RemoveHandler SiteMap.SiteMapResolve, AddressOf SiteMapResolve
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function SiteMapResolve(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SiteMapResolveEventArgs) As SiteMapNode

        Dim node As SiteMapNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode
        If IsThisTheNodeToChange(node) Then
            node = node.Clone()
            node.Title = GetNodeTitle()
        End If
        Return node

    End Function

End Class
```

This worked fine when the relevant page was navigated to, but unfortunately part of the site navigation involves a combo box that is data-bound to the site map like this:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="siteMapDataSource" runat="Server" ShowStartingNode="false" StartFromCurrentNode="false" StartingNodeOffset="1" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="pageMenu" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Url" />
```

When this menu is rendered, the `SiteMapResolve` event does not fire for any of the contents because the current node is the page on which the menu is defined. As a result, the menu shows the nonsense placeholder title from the physical sitemap file rather than the correct title.

**Attempt 2** - Writing my own sitemap provider. I didn't want to duplicate all the default behaviour, so I tried deriving from the default provider as follows.

```
Public Class DynamicXmlSiteMapProvider
    Inherits XmlSiteMapProvider

    Private _dataFixedUp As Boolean = False

    Public Overrides Function GetChildNodes(ByVal node As SiteMapNode) As SiteMapNodeCollection

        Dim result As SiteMapNodeCollection = MyBase.GetChildNodes(node)
        If Not _dataFixedUp Then
            For Each childNode As SiteMapNode In result
                FixUpNode(childNode)
            Next
        End If
        Return result

    End Function

    Private Sub FixUpNode(ByVal node As SiteMapNode)

        If IsThisTheNodeToChange(node) Then
            node.ReadOnly = False
            node.Title = GetNodeTitle()
            node.ReadOnly = True
            _dataFixedUp = True
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

This doesn't work because `GetChildNodes` doesn't appear to be called very often when navigating around the site.

**Attempt 3** - Try to fix the data immediately after it's loaded into memory, rather than when it's accessed.

```
Public Class DynamicXmlSiteMapProvider
    Inherits XmlSiteMapProvider

    Private _dataFixInProgress As Boolean = False
    Private _dataFixDone As Boolean = False

    Public Overrides Function BuildSiteMap() As SiteMapNode

        Dim result As SiteMapNode = MyBase.BuildSiteMap()
        If Not _dataFixInProgress AndAlso Not _dataFixDone Then
            _dataFixInProgress = True
            For Each childNode As SiteMapNode In result.GetAllNodes()
                FixUpNode(childNode)
            Next
            _dataFixInProgress = False
            _dataFixDone = True
        End If
        Return result

    End Function

    Private Sub FixUpNode(ByVal node As SiteMapNode)

        If IsThisTheNodeToChange(node) Then
            node.ReadOnly = False
            node.Title = GetNodeTitle()
            node.ReadOnly = True
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

This appears to work. However, I'm worried about the call to `GetAllNodes` in the `BuildSiteMap` method. It just seems wrong to me to recursively pull all data into memory just to fix up one value. Also, I have no control over when `BuildSiteMap` is called. I would prefer something more like Attempt 1, that is called on demand when the node data is first required.

**Attempt 4 (NEW)** - Like Attempt 2, but overriding *all* virtual members that are to do with reading data (`CurrentNode`, `FindSiteMapNode`, `FindSiteMapNodeFromKey`, `GetChildNodes`, `GetCurrentNodeAndHintAncestorNodes`, `GetCurrentNodeAndHintNeighborhoodNodes`, `GetParentNode`, `GetParentNodeRelativeToCurrentNodeAndHintDownFromParent`, `GetParentNodeRelativeToNodeAndHintDownFromParent`, `HintAncestorNodes`, `HintNeighborhoodNodes`), to try to intercept the reading of the dynamic node somewhere.

This did not work. I put debug statements in all the overridden members, and it seems that none of them at all are called when data binding to the dropdown list. The only explanation I can think of is that the nodes are all read into memory in one go during the `BuildSiteMap` call, so that the `SiteMapNode` is not hitting the provider class when enumerating child nodes.

Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed questioned. It helped a similar case that I had!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our Custom SiteMapProvider we override the BuildSiteMap Method and construct the SiteMapNodes manually. To change and/or add custom properties we add custom attributes to the SiteMapNodes by create a NameValueCollection and add pass this to the SiteMapNode Constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark, but if I do that then I will effectively be doing Attempt 3, and re-inventing the wheel as well.

Comment: True. Its not such a big wheel to re-implement and if you use a custom built Menu or other component its helps to have the ability to add additional properties.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close with attempt #2 - you just also need to override [**GetParentNode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.getparentnode.aspx) and **[FindSiteMapNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.findsitemapnode.aspx)** as well.

Comment: Rex, that did not make any difference I'm afraid (see my edit for Attempt 4). At the moment it looks like Attempt 3 is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark and Rex for the suggestions. What I ended up doing was leaving the sitemap provider alone and just fixing up the one node in the master page, thus:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    ' Do this as early as possible in the page lifecycle so that it happens before any
    ' automatic data binding or control initialisation is done.
    Dim node As SiteMapNode = GetNodeToEdit()
    Dim nodeReadOnly As Boolean = node.ReadOnly
    node.ReadOnly = False
    node.Title = GetNodeTitle()
    node.ReadOnly = nodeReadOnly

End Sub
```

However, I have accepted Mark's answer, because that's how I will do it if it turns out that more extensive modifications need to be done in future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Christian for your research.  Using your results, I've come up with the following that may help others:

```
' Dynamically update some menu items.
'
' Since the correct Medical Center ID is not known until runtime, need to
' append "&MEDICAL_CENTER_ID=xxx" to all of the report's URLs in Web.sitemap.
Public Shared Sub UpdateMenu(ByVal MedicalCenterID As String)
  Dim CurrentNodeTitle As String = ""
  Dim NodeReadOnlyProperty As Boolean

  ' Home menu item
  CurrentNodeTitle = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title

  ' Determines if the current node has child nodes.
  If (SiteMap.CurrentNode.HasChildNodes) Then
    ' Loop through top level 1 menu items (looking for Reports)
    For Each ChildNodesEnumerator1 As SiteMapNode In SiteMap.CurrentNode.ChildNodes
      CurrentNodeTitle = ChildNodesEnumerator1.Title
      If CurrentNodeTitle = "Reports" Then
        ' Loop through level 2 menu items (looking for specfic reports)
        For Each ChildNodesEnumerator2 As SiteMapNode In ChildNodesEnumerator1.ChildNodes
          CurrentNodeTitle = ChildNodesEnumerator2.Title
          If CurrentNodeTitle = "Multi-Day Vehicle Requests" Or _
           CurrentNodeTitle = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" Then
            ' First check if the URL has not been modified already
            If InStr(ChildNodesEnumerator2.Url, "MEDICAL_CENTER_ID") = 0 Then
              NodeReadOnlyProperty = ChildNodesEnumerator2.ReadOnly
              ChildNodesEnumerator2.ReadOnly = False
              ChildNodesEnumerator2.Url = ChildNodesEnumerator2.Url & "&MEDICAL_CENTER_ID=" & MedicalCenterID
              ChildNodesEnumerator2.ReadOnly = NodeReadOnlyProperty
            End If
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```